# modifying nested object by key do not trigger effect in NGRX

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an NGRX store looking like this :

```
export interface INavigationSettings {
  gridLayout: {
    [Breakpoints.Small]: GridLayout;
    [Breakpoints.Large]: GridLayout;
  };
  //...
}
```

I have an action that will apply modification to those GridLayout

```
const SET_NAVIGATION_GRID_VISIBILITY = (state: State, action: featureAction.SetNavigationGridVisibility) => {
  state.navigation.gridLayout[action.payload.size].visibility = {
    ...state.navigation.gridLayout[action.payload.size].visibility,
    ...action.payload.visibility
  };
  return state;
};
```

This change is correctly applied in the store [image]

The problem is, my selector `selectNavigationGridLayout`

```
export const selectSettingsState: MemoizedSelector<object, State> = createFeatureSelector<State>('settings');

export const gridLayout = (state: State): {
    Small: featureModels.GridLayout;
    Large: featureModels.GridLayout;
} => state.navigation.gridLayout;

export const selectNavigationGridLayout: MemoizedSelector<object, {
    Small: featureModels.GridLayout;
    Large: featureModels.GridLayout;
}> = createSelector(selectSettingsState, gridLayout);
```

Never catch any changes, and do not call the change state trough the app.
It was working fine before when I had a single object gridLayout, but since I am doing mobile, I separated 
in 2 pieces =>

```
  gridLayout: {
    [Breakpoints.Small]: GridLayout;
    [Breakpoints.Large]: GridLayout;
  };
```

and now it never triggers.

I also tried to

```
return {
   ...state
}
```

EDIT :

I changed to this

```
const SET_NAVIGATION_GRID_VISIBILITY = (state: State, action: featureAction.SetNavigationGridVisibility) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    navigation: {
      ...state.navigation,
      gridLayout: {
        ...state.navigation.gridLayout,
        [action.payload.size]: {
          ...state.navigation.gridLayout[action.payload.size],
          visibility: {
            ...state.navigation.gridLayout[action.payload.size].visibility,
            ...action.payload.visibility
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

and it works, but it's terrible, isn't there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last edit works because you are returning new state, not mutating the existing state.

Here are some "prettier" solutions to return new state.

## Solution 1: ActionReducerMap

Another solution is to use `ActionReducerMap` to decompose your reducers into being focused on a particular piece of state.

I see that your top-level feature is named `settings`.  So your store looks a little like this:

```
interface StoreState {
  settings: SettingsFeatureState;
}

interface SettingsFeatureState {
  navigation: INavigationSettings;
}

interface INavigationSettings {
  gridLayout: GridLayoutState;
}

interface GridLayoutState {
  [Breakpoints.Small]: GridLayout;
  [Breakpoints.Large]: GridLayout;
}
```

And your settings reducer looks like one of the two:

```
function settingsReducer(state: SettingsFeatureState, action: Action): SettingsFeatureState {
 // ...
}

// or

function navigationReducer(state: INavigationSettings, action: Action): INavigationSettings {
 // ...
}

const settingsReducer: ActionReducerMap<SettingsFeatureState> = {
  navigation: navigationReducer
};
```

Do the following steps to decompose your state reducers even more.

Create a grid layout reducer like this:

```
function gridLayoutReducer(state: GridLayoutState, action: Action): GridLayoutState {
  // ...
}

const SET_NAVIGATION_GRID_VISIBILITY = (state: GridLayoutState, action: featureAction.SetNavigationGridVisibility): GridLayoutState => {
  return {
    ...state,
    [action.payload.size]: {
      ...state[action.payload.size],
      visibility: {
        ...state[action.payload.size].visibility,
        ...action.payload.visibility
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Then, modify your navigationReducer register the `gridLayoutReducer` as follows:

```
const navigationReducerMap: ActionReducerMap<INavigationSettings> = {
  gridLayout: gridLayoutReducer
}

// This function has the following signature:
// navigationReducer(state: INavigationSettings, action: Action): INavigationSettings 
const navigationReducer = combineReducers(navigationReducerMap)
```

## Solution 2: Clone State

If you really don't want to return new state, you could keep your original logic with a slight modification using something like `lodash` to deep clone the state:

```
const SET_NAVIGATION_GRID_VISIBILITY = (state: State, action: featureAction.SetNavigationGridVisibility) => {
  const newState = _.deepClone(state)

  newState.navigation.gridLayout[action.payload.size].visibility = {
    ...newState.navigation.gridLayout[action.payload.size].visibility,
    ...action.payload.visibility
  };
  return newState;
};
```

This returns new state since you've completely cloned the state. This approach will use a lot more resources, however, since you're cloning the entire state just to modify a few properties.

Comment: is Solution 1 the same performance wise as my lengthy solution ?